# .htaccess causes 500 Internal Server Error on Not Found

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using .htaccess to add .php to files requested, so the request "/example" goes to "/example.php"

However, when "/example.php" doesn't exist, I get an Internal Server Error instead of a 404. How can I get it to work with 404, not 500?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try replacing:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
```

with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

So that the rule only gets applied if there's a file that ends with php that exists.